# malloc() causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, malloc

I am trying to implement the Linked List data structure for my college course, but on executing the code the following line produces an EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x8) error.

```
temp->next = (ptrtonode) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Following is the code in its entirety.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node *ptrtonode;
typedef ptrtonode header;

struct node
{
    int data;
    ptrtonode next;
};

ptrtonode create(int n)
{
    int i;
    header temphead = NULL;
    ptrtonode temp = temphead;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        temp->next = (ptrtonode) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Enter data for node %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &temp->next->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temphead;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    header head;
    int n;
    printf("How many nodes do you wish to create?");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    head = create(n);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

On first iteration of the `for` loop inside the `create()` function `temp` is `NULL`, which is then dereferenced causing the failure (not `malloc()` causing the failure). You will need to restructure the code slightly to prevent dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

Other points:

- casting the return value of `malloc()` is not required.
- check the result of `scanf()` to ensure `n` was assigned a valid integer (and confirm that the `int` is positive):

  ```
  /* scanf() returns the number of assignments made,
     which in this case should be 1. */
  if (1 == scanf("%d", &n) && n > 0)
  {
      /* 'n' assigned a sensible value. */
  }
  ```

Comment: If `temphead` isn't `NULL`, then during the `temp = temphead` assignment, Xcode spits out a warning: _Variable 'temphead' is uninitialized when used here_ and the program stops at the `malloc()` line. Says `Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1`

I don't get it. This seems to work in Fedora in college. What am I doing incorrectly now?
Oh, and I implemented your other points as well.

Comment: Never mind, I allocated memory to `temphead` before making the `temp = temphead` assignment. The program works just fine now. Thank you.